# angular http.get<boolean> doesn't return boolean properly

Tags: angular, spring-boot, get, boolean, httpclient

i implemented a get method in my spring boot applicaten that takes an email adress and returns a boolean true if the email adress is already persisted and false if it isn't.

i tested the method with postman and it returned the right value.

in my angular frontend i implemented this method in my service.ts:

```
isEmailAlreadyPersisted(email: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.httpClient.get<boolean>(this.authBaseUri + '/' +  email);
  }
```

in my component i implemented a method that subscribes to that service and returns the boolean.

But when I try to use that returned boolean, it's always the initialized "false" value.

```
private isEmailAlreadyPersisted(email: string): boolean {
    let bool: boolean = false;

    const observable: Observable<boolean> = this.authService.isEmailAlreadyPersisted(email);
    observable.subscribe({
      next: data => {
        bool = data;
        console.log("bool= " + bool);
        console.log("data=" + data);

      }
    })
    return bool;

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("return= " + this.isEmailAlreadyPersisted("admin@email.com"));
  }
```

these were the console logs:

return= false

bool= true

data=true

thx in advance!

~max

**Edit 1:**

I tried to subscribe into my validation function but it seems like the validation function always goes through as true. i think the "return false" inside the subscription isn't working.

```
private emailCheck(): boolean {
if (this.registerRequest.email.trim().length === 0) {
  this.toastr.error('Email can\'t be empty.');
  this.registerRequest.email = '';
  return false;
}
const expression: RegExp = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i;
if (!(expression.test(this.registerRequest.email))) {
  this.toastr.error('Email pattern doesn\'t fit.');
  this.registerRequest.email = '';
  return false;
}
this.isEmailAlreadyPersisted(this.registerRequest.email //admin@email.com).subscribe({
  next: data => {
    if (data) {
      this.toastr.error('Email already used.');
      this.registerRequest.email = '';
      return false;
    }
  }
})
return true;
```

}

Comment: You either need to put your return in the  `.subscribe` method -- Or you need to set bool outside the method. -- OR you need to **globalize** bool.  `bool` cannot be reached and set as it is out of scope.

Comment: You need to return the `observable` not the boolean.

Comment: @Zak i set a bool outside the method but it stayed undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `return` is set up sequentially while the observable is set up to wait for an update. As such, the `return` happens much earlier than you'd like.

You'll need a bit of asynchronous coding for this to work. This can be done by adding callbacks all the way to your `ngOnInit` function. You can continue to use the observer pattern:

```js
private isEmailAlreadyPersisted(email: string): boolean {
    const observable: Observable<boolean> = this.authService.isEmailAlreadyPersisted(email);
    return observer;

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isEmailAlreadyPersisted("admin@email.com").subscribe({
        next: data => {
             console.log("return= " + data);       
        }
    })
  }
```

Alternatively, the observer function can be wrapped into a promise:

```js
private isEmailAlreadyPersisted(email: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        const observable: Observable<boolean> = this.authService.isEmailAlreadyPersisted(email);
         observable.subscribe({
          next: data => {
            res(data);
          }
        })
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isEmailAlreadyPersisted("admin@email.com")
        .then(bool => {
            console.log("return= " + bool);
        })
  }
```

Comment: thanks that helped, but i want to use that method to validate my email input in the frontend. i used that in my validate method but it always goes through for some reason.

i edited my main post to show you the problem

Comment: That's fine but you will need to do some sort of asynchronous flow to achieve that no matter what, as your auth service is not behaving synchronously.